# Unittest on GCP Storage blob

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, google-cloud-platform, pytest

I have one query regarding the Unittest of storage triggered GCP cloud function.

The structure of the Cloud function is like below:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def entry_func(event, context):
    # some operations
    blob_lists = <bucket_storage>.list_blobs(prefix = f'some_string')
    some_other_func(blob_lists)

def some_other_func(list_of_blobs: Iterator):
    list1, list2 = [], []
    for blob in list_of_blobs:
        if blob.name.endswith('some_string'):
            list1.append(blob)
        elif blob.name.endswith('some_other_string'):
            list2.append(blob)
    return list1, list2
```

How can I write the unit test cases for both functions using pytest?

How can I mock the `list_of_blobs` object as it is an iterator of objects and also check if statements are working or not?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it using below test code

```
import main.py # My source file

class Blob:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

@pytest.fixture
def my_sample_fixture():
    return [Blob("sample_some_string"), Blob("sample_some_other_string")]


def test_some_other_func(my_sample_fixture):
    list1, list2 = main.some_other_func(my_sample_blobs)
    assert "sample_file1.txt" in [file.name for file in list1]
    assert "sample_file2.txt" in [file.name for file in list2]
```

Comment: What is the reason that you used pytest for unit testing ? you could write in golang itself.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know golang